# How to fix: No executable found matching command "dotnet-dslc"?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio-mac

I am conducting a literature survey for my thesis and was trying PROSE SDK by Microsoft. However, whenever I try to build the dependencies of the project from their sample [repo] (https://github.com/microsoft/prose), I get this error:

```
Target CompileGrammar:
    dotnet dslc  "@/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/obj/ProseSample.Substrings.rsp" 
    dotnet dslc  "@/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/obj/ProseSample.Substrings.rsp"
    No executable found matching command "dotnet-dslc"
```

I followed installation instructions from [here](https://microsoft.github.io/prose/)

Here's the information regarding dotnet configuration:

macOS: High Sierra Version 10.13.6
Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.0.9
`dotnet --info`

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.106
 Commit:    aa79b139a8

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.13
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.13-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.106/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.4
  Commit:  f95848e524

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.105 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.106 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And here is .csproj file:

`ProseSample.Substrings.csproj`

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net45</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics\ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.Common" Version="6.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.DslcTargets" Version="6.20.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.Dslc" Version="6.20.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Build Output:

```
Building ProseSample (Debug)
Build started 6/1/2019 5:53:06 PM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo:
  Skipping target "CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreCompile:
  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Touching "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics/obj/Debug/net45/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics.csproj.CopyComplete".
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics -> /Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics/bin/Debug/net45/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics.dll
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/ProseSample.Substrings.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/ProseSample.Substrings.csproj" is building "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

Target ResolveProjectReferences:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/ProseSample.Substrings.csproj" is building "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/ProseSample.Substrings.csproj" is building "/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics/ProseSample.Substrings.Semantics.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CompileGrammar:
    dotnet dslc  "@/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/obj/ProseSample.Substrings.rsp" 
    dotnet dslc  "@/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/obj/ProseSample.Substrings.rsp"
    No executable found matching command "dotnet-dslc"
    /Users/username/.nuget/packages/microsoft.programsynthesis.dslctargets/6.20.0/build/Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.DslcTargets.targets(82,9): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet dslc  "@/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/obj/ProseSample.Substrings.rsp"" exited with code 1.
Done building target "CompileGrammar" in project "ProseSample.Substrings.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "ProseSample.Substrings.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Users/username/.nuget/packages/microsoft.programsynthesis.dslctargets/6.20.0/build/Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.DslcTargets.targets(82,9): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet dslc  "@/Users/username/test/prose/ProgramSynthesis/ProseSample.Substrings/obj/ProseSample.Substrings.rsp"" exited with code 1.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.21

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With the latest [PROSE v7.11.1](https://microsoft.github.io/prose/release-notes/#release-7111---20200515) and the steps below, the build seems to pass on macOS now.

The build failure is trigeered by `dotnet dslc` tool [failing to run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues#executable-file-not-found) on your environment.

First, this tool seems to be a part of the NuGet package that needs to be installed

```sh
$ cd ProseSample
$ dotnet add package Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.Dslc --version 7.11.1
```

Next, it seems that the cross-platform way to run this tool responsible for mandatory step of DSL code generation is different - `dotnet run dslc`.

```sh
$ dotnet run dslc
$ dotnet build

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

I presume that in order for build to work in IDE, one also have to edit `~.nuget/packages/microsoft.programsynthesis.dslctargets/7.11.1/build/Microsoft.ProgramSynthesis.DslcTargets.targets` and replace all 2 occurrence of `dotnet dslc` with the `dotnet run dslc`.

Hope this helps!